# How do I implement this snowfall code within an email?

Tags: html, css

I found this code at http://freshinbox.com/blog/ambient-animations-in-email-snow-and-stars/ and liked the effect. Though when I put it into my email it creates a huge white space between the tables.

How do I insert this into an email correctly? Do I need to place the div tags in a certain place?

```
<style>
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 0) {
 .animcontainer{
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  height:200px;
  overflow:hidden;
  background-color:#007FFF;
 }
 .snow{
  border-radius:9px;
  height:18px;
  width:18px;
  position:absolute;
  top:-20px;
  background-color:#ffffff;
 }
 .snow1{
  -webkit-animation: snowanim1 5s linear 0s infinite; 
 }
 .snow2{
  -webkit-animation: snowanim2 6s linear 1s infinite; 
 }
 .snow3{
  -webkit-animation: snowanim3 7s linear 2s infinite; 
 }
 @-webkit-keyframes snowanim1
 {
  0% { top:0%;left:50%; }        
  100% { top:100%;left:65%; }
 }
 @-webkit-keyframes snowanim2
 {
  0% { top:0%;left:30%; }        
  100% { top:100%;left:25%; }
 }
 @-webkit-keyframes snowanim3
 {
  0% { top:0%;left:70%; }        
  100% { top:100%;left:60%; }
 }
}
</style>
```

.

```
<div class="animcontainer">
  <div class="snow snow1"></div>
  <div class="snow snow2"></div>
  <div class="snow snow3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: HTML for emails is not like HTML for the web. Different email clients will probably all break this in different ways.

Comment: I know it won't work in some clients, I just want to know how this would be inserted.

Comment: Also I will add that the code I posted was designed for emails according to the creator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out in the end, it makes no difference where the div tags are. What was causing the issues was the animcontainer.

There is one issue I could not solve however and that was the animation not reaching the bottom of the page despite being "top:100%" within the animation, so I had to do 2000% to actually reach the bottom which does not look like an elegant solution.